# < was unexpected at this time

Tags: python, command-line, windows-7, cmd, confluence

I am getting an error on the below python script when run in cmd, when I run that command by itself in cmd, it runs perfectly fine. I'm not sure what may have caused this problem.

The error is: `< was unexpected at this time`

```
command = "confluence --action storePage --space 'EN' --title 'csoap-235' --parent '@home' --special ' # ~' --content '<p><ac:link><ri:page ri:content-title=~Home~/></ac:link></p>' --noConvert --server 'server' --user 'username' --password 'pswd'" 
os.system(command)
print "This happened"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the error raised by python interpreter or `confluence` command?

Comment: There are some escape sequence as u use `<></>` in your code string command. Please try without that part.

Comment: @WKPlus, The error was raised when I ran it in the command line

Comment: @Lafada Those are actually integral to my command.. I'm trying to use that content exactly as it is

Comment: You have to escape special characters. & seperates commands on a line.

`&&` executes this command only if previous command's errorlevel is 0.

`||` (not used above) executes this command only if previous command's errorlevel is NOT 0

`>` output to a file

`>>` append output to a file

`<` input from a file

`|` output of one command into the input of another command

`^` escapes any of the above, including itself, if needed to be passed to a program

Comment: @D.Ddgg That seems like single command

Comment: @aishpr Just escape the special characters. You should be good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, i don't know anything about python, but in `cmd` you have a problem with the quotes. Change the quotes in the command to use double quotes instead of single quotes. Single quotes are not recognized as a valid quoting in cmd, so, the characters `<` and `>` in your command are found out of a quoted string and considered as part of the command, that is, a redirection

```
command = r'confluence --action storePage --space "EN" --title "csoap-235" --parent "@home" --special " # ~" --content "<p><ac:link><ri:page ri:content-title=~Home~/></ac:link></p>" --noConvert --server "server" --user "username" --password "pswd"' 
os.system(command)
print "This happened"
```

Not tested, it is written according to documentation/samples.